# Excel 2016 icons missing from pin list upon boot

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, icons, start-menu

After I upgraded to Windows 10 Fall Creators Update, when I start Windows 10 x64, the files I have pinned to MS Office have some of their associated icons missing as in this example:
[image: Pin list immediately after boot]
But after I open any Excel file (not necessarily one in the pin list), the icons are there:
[image: Pin list after opening a file]
This is only mildly annoying, but I'd like to fix it. I have tried Googling some variations of "icons missing from pinned list," but I don't get anything close to my issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though there may be issues with the Font Cache on your computer. Create a .bat file with this code and run it:

```
ie4uinit.exe -show
taskkill /F /IM explorer.exe
cd /d %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer
attrib -h iconcache_*.db
DEL /A /Q "%localappdata%\IconCache.db"
DEL /A /F /Q "%localappdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\iconcache*"
start explorer
shutdown -r -t 10
```

**IMPORTANT:** This WILL forcibly restart your computer right away. Make sure everything is saved and closed before you run it.

The script does **not** need to run as Administrator.

Once the computer restarts, give it a few minutes, open Excel, close it, restart again, and see if your icons show up correctly.

Comment: +1 for the effort. I tried your batch file to no avail. I also thought you may have meant "icon cache" rather than "font cache," so I tried solutions offered here: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/rebuild-icon-clear-thumbnail-cache-windows-10 and here:http://www.thewindowsclub.com/icon-cache-rebuilder-for-windows-10. Neither of these worked either.

Comment: Hmm. I'm sorry to hear that. I hope someone else shares (or you find) a solution.